# Как поочередно выдавать значения?

Tags: php

Хочу написать такую функцию, которая бы принимала 3 значения:

```
имя1, имя2, количество_раз

newFunc('Алексей', 'Дмитрий', 5);
```

И нужно чтобы она работала так:

```
выполняется 5 переборов
1 = Алексей
2 = Дмитрий
3 = Алексей
4 = Дмитрий
5 = Алексей
```

И в результат чтобы вернуло

```
return 'Алексей';
```

Буду благодарен за полезную информацию.

Comment: и кой смысл делать эти 5 бессмысленных переборов? если четное, то выдаете первое имя,  нечетное, то второе. сделали `func($n1, $n2, $num)` сложили в массив `$n = [$n1, $n2]` и вернули `$n[$num%2]`

Comment: но если суть в том, чтобы реализовать "счеталочку" с выводом, то другое дело

Comment: @teran не обязательно конечно эти 5 переборов. Главное чтобы результат был как после 5 переборов. Собственно за лучшим решением этой задачи я сюда и написал)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если имен всего два, то результат будет зависеть от того, четное число передано или нет

```
function myFunc($name1, $name2, $num){
    $names = [$name1, $name2];
    return $names[$num % 2];
}
```

Более интересна была бы общая задача, когда первым аргументом передавалось число, а далее следовало бы переменное число аргументов - имен. Нечто похожее на это:

```
function func($num, ...$names){
    return $names[$num % count($names)];
}

func(100, 'Василий', 'Иннокентий', 'Кирилл')
```

Или  если есть особое желание передавать число последним аргументом то

```
function func(...$values){
    $num = array_pop($values);
    ...
}
```

Comment: как-то не правильно вывело: `myFunc('Aleksei', 'Dmitrii', 5);` - результат: *Dmitrii* , хотя должен быть **Aleksei**

Comment: @Денис поменяйте их в `$names` местами

Comment: менять местами нельзя, порядок должен сохранятся. я так понял что так получается из-за того что нумерация массива идет с нуля, поэтому если **num** передавать на 1 больше - выдает правильный результат. Я прав?

Comment: не надо ничего передавать больше, вы либо делаете `$names = [$name2, $name1]` (меняете местами элементы массива, как я написал выше), либо  при возврате результата делаете `($num + 1)%2`. В любом случае, на формат входных данных это никак не влияет. Но первое, очевидно, проще.

Answer (score 1):

Вам пригодится деление с остатком.

Псевдокод (т.к. php уже изрядно подзабыл) функции на любое количество людей:

```
$data = array("Алексей", "Борис", "Виктор", 10) // пример входных данных

func schitalochka ($input)
{
   $num = array_pop($input);
   $number_of_people = count($input);
   $pos = $num % $number_of_people + 1;
   return $input[$pos];
}
```

- `$num` - число.
- `$number_of_people` - количество людей.
- `$pos` - нужная нам позиция. Прибавляем единицу, т.к. нумерация элементов массива начинается с 0, а мы считаем с 1.